# php way to retrieve search query from yandex, google, etc

Tags: php, string, search

It would seem most major SE's are now hiding the actual query from the referrer, which makes getting the data quite difficult. Is anyone aware of a PHP way of retrieving the hidden data and translate it back into something human readable?

Comment: You shouldn't do it, because those search engine will change the way they secure, just use API like: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/ or https://tech.yandex.com/sitesearch/

Comment: Thanks for the hint -- and sorry for coming back sort of late. External API stuff gives me the creeps, hence I'll have to do without.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way. the data is no longer sent. It's not hidden or encrypted, it does not exist.

Comment: If it wouldn't exist, the whole thing didn't make much sense, would it? It's certainly being sent to Google, Yandex, etc. There's a hint towards Base64 in the Yandex referrer, but just about any decoder throws an error complaining about an invalid string so I presume it's a native algorithm by either of the SE's. Thanks anyway.

Comment: i don't think we are talking about he same thing - if you click a link on  google search - the referrer strips the search terms so the site you go to knows, "google" but not the search  used - you seem to be talking about something else?

Comment: Actually I'm not, but perhaps my spelling was off-track, sorry. Google and Co are making money because THEY do get that data. However, I have a feeling -- confirming what you mentioned -- that the current procedure would be like a) SE receives the query, b) re-formats the refrerrer, and c) returns the result to the screen. That would imply one would have to pay whatever these punks decide to charge to learn how people found the site. Splendid...

Comment: they mostly did this for privacy, there has been a lot written about it. of course they get the data, how else do they return the search result. I'm not sure the problem here.  I strip my referrer for privacy. sits ii hae that log it - its just sapmmed anyway so useless

Comment: That's the theory ;) If you don't mind me asking, how do _you_ know what users where searching for before arriving at one of your sites; or has it already become something way too trivial to even bother about? Personally I tend to doubt search has anymore to do with /privacy/ then a candybar with agriculture. Looks more like plain monopoly and outright piracy.

Comment: i really don't care, i'm not in the SEO businesses(more scam than business).

Comment: Frankly it has nothing to do with SEO, as in search engine optimisation. I was just curious how to access a data segment to help me understand how folks find a given site or page. Well, enough commenting for today. Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: well they use to do it, now they don't, when they did you got a bot load of referrer spam, so I have no personal problem with it - wounder what google analytics does now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89974/discussion-between-phclaus-and-dagon).